# Can't parse varchar YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:ss in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I have the following varchar(20): `2013-05-20T00:00:00`  that I need to parse into a datetime object in MYSQL.

I parse using `STR_TO_DATE(field_effective_date_value, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')`
but the result is null. When I try to insert into the database I get the error:

`Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '2013-05-20T00:00:00' for function str_to_date`

How do I parse this varchar into a date in MYSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your format mask - it should be `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%S'`

```
select STR_TO_DATE(field_effective_date_value, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%S')
```